# Adding new user for remote desktop, Windows 8.1

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-8.1

I have a desktop to which I remote in via rdp using my laptops, tablets etc., everything works fine here. (Username: MicrosoftAccount\myemail@outlook.com, password: mypass)

I want to give another user remote access to this desktop. So I added his email address (abc@outlook.com) via "Manage other accounts", enabled remote access for this email via "System Properties" --> "Remote" --> "Select Users"

Now, when he tries to login using his email, Username: MicrosoftAccount\abc@outlook.com, password: HisOutlookPassword, via RDP, he gets error "the credentials that were used to connect to MyDesktop did not work. Please enter new credentials."

Anything I am missing? Does he need to physically login to my desktop for the first time?

All OSes we use are Windows 8.1 Pro

Comment: I assume both users are in the game user group?

Comment: was that 'same user group'? Yes, Both are in administrators group (Local groups).

Comment: Try logging into the computer with the Microsoft Account so the user profile directory is created.

Comment: Is there anyway around it? I wont be at the physical machine for atleast another month. I generally use my ip to Remote-in into my desktop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RDP to User with Microsoft Account](http://superuser.com/questions/645770/rdp-to-user-with-microsoft-account)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround.

Creating a local account, I was able to remote-in using LocalAccount\Username.
Logging in as this local account, he was able to switch it to his MicrosoftAccount and remotein without issues.

As Ramhound said, think it has to do with user profile directory not being created for a MicrosoftAccount unless you physically login to the system.