# Can you force windows 10 mail to use a password

Tags: windows-10, email, auto-login

I would like to know if it is possible to force the integrated windows mail to use a password, after your Hotmail account is linked. If possible can a pin be used as well.

Example log in to windows with your password, or pin, then click on the windows mail tile, and instead of it auto opening, you get a prompted to enter password.

Answer (score 0):

No, and it doesn't really make sense to do it, you log in with the same password/pin anyway. Then Windows regularly sync your OneDrive folder, mail, contact & calendar with the very same token. Just switch to local account, or create a additional account for someone you trust to use your computer but not to your mail

Comment: I've been trying to get Windows remote desktop to work for a while now, but was having difficult time with one Pc on a standard micrsoft account, and the other 2 using my email, as a login. I decided to recently see If I could get it working right using Microsoft accounts on all computers. It seems to be working with this configuration, but now I have the PC down stairs in the music room with a Microsoft email open, and I would like to have that PC with out email access, because I normally allow my buddy to login if he needs to. Is it possible to uninstall this integrated windows mail?

Comment: Update I was able to use power shell to reset to before you actually put your email, and password into mail, for sign in purposes using this power shell command. Get-AppxPackage *windowscommunicationsapps* | Remove-AppxPackage I found out how to from this link. http://www.howtogeek.com/224798/how-to-uninstall-windows-10s-built-in-apps-and-how-to-reinstall-them/

Comment: Well thought i had it but no luck

Comment: Ah, XY Problem. I suggest try to fix the remote desktop permission first (either by [loosing the security requirement](http://superuser.com/questions/645770/rdp-to-user-with-microsoft-account) or use [microsoftaccount](https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1241040-remote-desktop-when-using-microsoft-account-for-login/) as domain name.

Comment: I don't know what this XY Problem is. When you say loose the security requirement, are you talking about stopping the need for passwords? Is it possible to say make one computer password free on a standard account, and keep Microsoft Hotmail accounts on the other two PC's.

Comment: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Anyway if you actually read the answer on the first link you'll understand what I mean with loosing the security question, and in the second link you'll see it doesn't matter whether a PC have a password or not if you just want to connect to another PC via RDP

Comment: Your buddy should have his own login on your computer. Do not share logins with anyone you do not want seeing all your account data.